# How can I create a plugin class for product save method when it is called from API?

Tags: magento2, api, plugin

How can I create a plugin class to intercept the save product method, with an around method, but only when this is a request from API, is it possible? Thanks in advance.

[Edit]

My current structure:
**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="name-integrations" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And My ProductPlugin class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class ProductPlugin
{    
    public function aroundSave
    (
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, 
        $saveOptions = false, 
        \Closure $proceed
    ){
        // logging to test override    
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Here: '.__METHOD__ . ' - ' . __LINE__);

        // call the core observed function
        $returnValue = $proceed(); 

        // logging to test override        
        $logger->debug(__METHOD__ . ' - ' . __LINE__);

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
?>
```

But When I execute this via API, I get this error: `"message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5aabfd61c4d51"`

And in log I get:

> [2018-03-16 17:22:41] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5aabfd61c4d51; Message: Plugin class Gluk\Integracoes\Plugin\ProductPlugin doesn't exist {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5aabfd61c4d51; Message: Plugin class Gluk\Integracoes\Plugin\ProductPlugin doesn't exist at /opt/lampp/htdocs/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Plugin class Gluk\Integracoes\Plugin\ProductPlugin doesn't exist at /opt/lampp/htdocs/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:182)"} []

It is sayng that this plugin doesn't exists, and I cant see where is my mistake, I've already runned `bin/magento setup:di:compile` successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `di.xml` file in you module inside the folders `etc/webapi_rest` or `etc/webapi_soap` that file will be taken into account only when on api rest or api soap context.
So I guess you can write your plugin for the interface `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` for method `save`, but declare it in `di.xml` inside the folders mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tryed like you sayd, but I got some errors, can you see my new edit please?